# Why does Polyhedron render well on its own but not in combination with complete model

Tags: rendering, openscad

The code below is an attempt to make a simple 3d triangle to work as side supports for a larger model.

It works well on its own, but when i add it to a larger model, one of the sides of the triangle does not render and I am getting warnings of **"UI-WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair!"**

To make it even stranger, when I click "save", the model is redrawn and the model shows up complete with the missing side.

I am using OpenScad v.2019.05

I am working around the problem by making a few small objects and hull() around them. I would prefer this code to work, however.

```
//For some odd reason, this module works well on its own.
//It does does not render correctly when used as part of a larger model.
//Then it will miss a side.
//It shows correctly up when saving though. 

module supportTriangle(height=10, length=10, thickness=10){
    trianglePoints = [
    [ 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ thickness, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, height ],
    [ thickness, 0, height],
    [ 0, length, 0],
    [ thickness, length, 0]];

    triangleFaces = [
    [ 0, 1, 5, 4 ],
    [ 0, 1, 3, 2 ],
    [ 2, 3, 5, 4 ], 
    [ 0, 4, 2 ],
    [ 1, 3, 5 ]];

    polyhedron(trianglePoints, triangleFaces);

}
```

I am getting warnings of "UI-WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair!" when rendering in combination with larger model

Comment: That happens because a couple of the faces are flipped - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/FAQ#Why_is_my_model_showing_up_with_F5_but_not_F6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
module supportTriangle(height=10, length=10, thickness=10){
    trianglePoints = [
    [ 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ thickness, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, height ],
    [ thickness, 0, height],
    [ 0, length, 0],
    [ thickness, length, 0]];

    triangleFaces = [
    [ 0, 1, 5, 4 ], 
    [ 2,3,1,0], // i reversed these to keep them clockwise 
    [ 4,5,3,2 ], // i reversed these to keep them clockwise 
    [ 0, 4, 2 ],
    [ 1, 3, 5 ]];

    polyhedron(trianglePoints, triangleFaces);

}
supportTriangle(10,10,10);
cube(5,center=true); // just an extra thing to make it error if order is wrong
```

see:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Primitive_Solids#polyhedron
All faces must have points ordered in the same direction . OpenSCAD prefers clockwise **when looking at each face from outside inwards**. The back is viewed from the back, the bottom from the bottom, etc..